# Use json in script on the view in MVC3

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, json.net, jqplot

I have the following problem:

First I have a method in the controller, which return PartialView with model in Json format.
Secondly I need to initialize the graphics (I using jqPlot - initialization this graphics implemented in JavaScript and it needs data in Json format). I want to take data from the model.

Question:
How can I get data from the model, then to work with them in the javascript?

Model:

```
public class GraphicDataModel
{
    public List<string> ValuesX { get; set; }
    public List<double> ValuesY { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ProcessesInPlanGraphic(int? versionId)
    {
        //...some business logic
        var model = Json(new{ model = GraphicDataModel }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return PartialView("ColumnBar", model);
    }
```

View:

```
@model ??? WHAT SHOULD I GIVE HERE ???

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

       //??? HOW TO GET HERE DATA FROM MODEL ???

        $.jqplot('BarChartForPlan', [ValuesY], {
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true }
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: ValuesX
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    pad: 1.05,
                    tickOptions: { formatString: '$%d' }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I use Ajax to initialize all works. A working example:

```
public ActionResult FetchGraphData()
{
    return Json(new {valuesX = ValuesX, valuesY = ValuesY}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Code from Javascript:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("FetchGraphData", "Home")';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (result) {
        //Call function to initialize graphics
        testJqPlot(result.valuesX, result.valuesY);
    }
});
```

I really need your help